# How to update a column value only upon the first change in another columns value Grouped by two different columns?

Tags: sql, h2

I  am working with H2 DB and have a schema name ***STUDENT*** and table name ***POS***

The ***POS*** table has the following attributes :

**ID_NUMBER** : It is unique for each row. 
**PARTITION_ID** : It is unique for each **STUDENT_ID**. It resets to 1 for a 
                   new **STUDENT_ID**.
**STDUENT_ID** : Just an ID for each student.
**ACTION** : The field to be updated. Explained below
**LEVEL** : Academic Level. 1 signifies Undergrad and 2 for Masters.
**POS** : The program of study

```
ID_NUMBER   || PARTITION_ID  || STUDENT_ID  || ACTION || LEVEL || POS   
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    1        || 1             || 8888        ||        || 1     || A
    2        || 2             || 8888        ||        || 1     || A
    3        || 3             || 8888        ||        || 1     || A
    4        || 4             || 8888        ||        || 1     || A 
    5        || 5             || 8888        ||        || 1     || B
    6        || 6             || 8888        ||        || 1     || C
    7        || 7             || 8888        ||        || 1     || C
    8        || 8             || 8888        ||        || 1     || C
    9        || 9             || 8888        ||        || 2     || D
    10       || 10            || 8888        ||        || 2     || E
    11       || 11            || 8888        ||        || 2     || E
    12       || 12            || 8888        ||        || 2     || E
    13       || 1             || 9999        ||        || 1     || B
    14       || 2             || 9999        ||        || 1     || A
    15       || 3             || 9999        ||        || 1     || A
    16       || 4             || 9999        ||        || 1     || A
    17       || 5             || 9999        ||        || 1     || B
    18       || 6             || 9999        ||        || 1     || B
    19       || 7             || 9999        ||        || 1     || B
    20       || 8             || 9999        ||        || 1     || B
    21       || 9             || 9999        ||        || 2     || D
    22       || 10            || 9999        ||        || 2     || D
    23       || 11            || 9999        ||        || 2     || D
    24       || 12            || 9999        ||        || 2     || D
```

Logic to update the Action Column:

If the **POS** changes between the same Level, I need to update the **ACTION** column with *CHANGE* where the first change occured.

Whatever is the last occurance of the **POS** within the same level, should be marked with *COMP*

So the final output should be as below:

```
 ID_NUMBER   || PARTITION_ID  || STUDENT_ID  || ACTION || LEVEL || POS   
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    1        || 1             || 8888        ||        || 1     || A
    2        || 2             || 8888        ||        || 1     || A
    3        || 3             || 8888        ||        || 1     || A
    4        || 4             || 8888        ||        || 1     || A 
    5        || 5             || 8888        || CHANGE || 1     || B
    6        || 6             || 8888        || CHANGE || 1     || C
    7        || 7             || 8888        ||        || 1     || C
    8        || 8             || 8888        || COMP   || 1     || C
    9        || 9             || 8888        ||        || 2     || D
    10       || 10            || 8888        || CHANGE || 2     || E
    11       || 11            || 8888        ||        || 2     || E
    12       || 12            || 8888        || COMP   || 2     || E
    13       || 1             || 9999        ||        || 1     || B
    14       || 2             || 9999        || CHANGE || 1     || A
    15       || 3             || 9999        ||        || 1     || A
    16       || 4             || 9999        ||        || 1     || A
    17       || 5             || 9999        || CHANGE || 1     || B
    18       || 6             || 9999        ||        || 1     || B
    19       || 7             || 9999        ||        || 1     || B
    20       || 8             || 9999        || COMP   || 1     || B
    21       || 9             || 9999        ||        || 2     || D
    22       || 10            || 9999        ||        || 2     || D
    23       || 11            || 9999        ||        || 2     || D
    24       || 12            || 9999        || COMP   || 2     || D
```

Now I wrote a SQL code to achieve *COMP* status. This is as below:

```
UPDATE STUDENT.POS AB
SET AB.ACTION = 'COMPLETE'
WHERE AB.PARTITION_ID =  (SELECT MAX(PARTITION_ID) 
FROM STUDENT.POS BC
WHERE BC.STUDENT_ID = AB.STUDENT_ID AND BC.LEVEL = AB.LEVEL)
```

My question is how to go about with updating the *CHANGE* status for only the first occurance of a change within each academic level for each student ?

NOTE: I am using H2 DB which currently does not support functions like Partition By or Over!

I tried running a sub-query. Something like below:

```
UPDATE STUDENT.POS AB 
SET AB.ACTION = 'CHANGE' 
WHERE AB.PARTITION_ID =  (SELECT BC.PARTITION_ID
FROM UPDATE STUDENT.POS BC 
WHERE  BC.LEVEL = AB.LEVEL AND BC.POS != AB.POS) 
AND BC.STUDENT_ID = AB.STUDENT_ID
```

Although, this results in an error saying: *Scalar Subquery contains more than one row*. Ironically, that is what I am trying to achieve with updating more than one row for each Level under each Student ID.

Comment: If you cannot use ranking function, can you do a stored procedure with cursor?

Comment: I could actually write a stored proc, but haven't really worked with those before. I guess it's time to try out new things.

Comment: I don't know H2, but here the documentation : 
http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#user_defined_functions